# How can I remove last frame of video?

Tags: objective-c

I want to delete the last frame of video. I have tried the following code but not getting the correct duration to delete the frame.

```
CMTime start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 600);
CMTime duration1 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.7, 600);
CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration1);
```

**EDIT:**
I want to delete the last frame of video. I have tried the following code but not getting the correct duration to delete the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

```
 AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:URl options:nil];

float timeRangeOfVideo=(videoAsset.duration.value/600)-0.2;
CMTime timeToAdd   = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((videoAsset.duration.value/600)-0.02,15);
```